# Access list and add strings to list from switch cases

Tags: c#

Okay, I hope the code below explain what I mean better.

The point of my program is to save user input in a list which also can be read by user. I want to keep it simple as possible. Appreciate a lot if you have any good idea of where to read more about cases like this.

Maybe ilist is an option in this case?

```
           class Store
           {
           Public void List<string> store = new List<string>
           Public static string store;
           Public static string pizza;
           }
          static void Main(string[] args)
         {

           switch (true)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("What type of pizza do you prefer?");
                    pizza = Console.ReadLine();
                    store.Add(pizza);

               break;

                case 2:
                   Console.WriteLine("The following pizza where prefered:")
                   foreach (string user in store)
                   Console.WriteLine(user);

                   break;
                   }
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's really hard to tell what you're trying to do, exactly what you've tried, and what happened. A [mcve] will make this *much* clearer.

Comment: Where do you put your data into the list?

Comment: Pls post code and also rephrase your question little bit more...Right now it is difficult to understand your problem and expected behaviour

Comment: Hope my edit sort out what I actually mean.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand your requirements properly. Do you mean you had problem with something like the following?

```
   var class1 = new Class1();
   class1.ExecuteCase(1);
   class1.ExecuteCase(2);

    public class Class1
    {
        private List<string> T = new List<string>();

        public void ExecuteCase(int caseNumber)
        {
            switch (caseNumber)
            {
                case 1:
                    var question = "question1";
                    T.Add(question);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    foreach (string declare in T)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(declare);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```